# Expected value of a random variable with an exponential distribution derived from the moment generating function

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Goal: expected value from the moment generating function.

I've the a random variable with an exponential law, its probability density function is (parameter $\lambda=1$):

$$
f_Z(z) = e^{- z} \quad \text{if } z \geq 0
$$

$$
f_Z(z) = 0 \qquad \quad \, \text{if } z < 0
$$

The moment generating function is:

$$
\begin{align}
MGF_Z(t) &= \displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}} e^{t \, z} \, f_1(z) \, dz = \\
&= \displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{+ \infty}} e^{t \, z} \, e^{-z} \, dz = \\
&= \displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{+ \infty}} e^{(t - 1) \, z} \, dz = \\
&= \frac{1}{t - 1} \, \left[ e^{(t - 1) \, z} \right]_{0}^{+ \infty}
\end{align}
$$

$$
MGF_Z(t < -1) = \frac{1}{1 - t}
$$

$$
MGF_Z(t \geq -1) = + \infty \quad
$$

The expected value is:

$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = MGF_Z'(0)
$$

How can I evaluate the $MGF_Z'(0)$? The $MGF_Z(t)$ is not infinite only for $t < - 1$.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\frac1{1-t}$?  What is this when $t=0$?

Comment: Hello @Henry the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-t}$ is $\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}$. But this is true only for $t<-1$.

Comment: You have a small error: the MGF exists when $t < 1$, not $t < -1$. And fortunately, $0 < 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much @angryavian